# How can I unit test a method that calls a method in a base class?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, xunit

I am using Moq to pass dependencies to the class I need to test. This is the constructor and method to test:

```
public class PosPortalApiService : PosPortalApiServiceBase, IPosPortalApiService {


    private readonly string _apiEndpoint;

    public PosPortalApiService ( IDependencyResolver dependencyResolver,
                                 IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings ) : base    ( dependencyResolver ) {
        _apiEndpoint = appSettings.Value.ApiEndpoint;
    }

public async Task<IEnumerable<IStore>> GetStoresInfo ( string userId ) {
        var endpoint = GetEndpointWithAuthorization(_apiEndpoint + StoresForMapEndpoint, userId);
        var encryptedUserId = EncryptionProvider.Encrypt(userId);

        var result = await endpoint.GetAsync(new {
            encryptedUserId
        });

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Store>>(result);
    }
```

GetEndpointWithAuthorisation is in the base class, it calls the DB. How can i approach testing this? I have the following so far:

```
[Fact]
    public void GetStoresInfoReturnsStoresForUser()
    {

        var mockHttpHandler = new MockHttpMessageHandler();
        var mockHttpClient = new HttpClient(mockHttpHandler);
        //mockHttpHandler.When("http://localhost/api/select/info/store/*")
        //                .Respond("application/json",  );
        AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings() { ApiEndpoint = "http://localhost" };
        var encryptedUserId = EncryptionProvider.Encrypt("2");                       
        var mockDependancyResolver = new Mock<IDependencyResolver>();

        var mockIOptions = new Mock<IOptions<AppSettings>>();
        IOptions<AppSettings> options = Options.Create(appSettings);
        //Arrange
        PosPortalApiService ApiService = new PosPortalApiService(mockDependancyResolver.Object, options);

        var sut = ApiService.GetStoresInfo("2");
```

It runs though until the base method call. Should I be providing a Mock response somehow? How would you do approach this test? Thanks.

Comment: You'd mock the dependency, the db, to return a fake value.

Comment: Do you know how i would setup the method if its in the base class?

Comment: How did the base class obtain the db dependency? You just need to provide your `PosPortalApiService` with the mocked dependency. The fact that the implementation is in the base class doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock the method in the base class (assuming it's either `virtual` or `abstract`) by making the `PosPortalApiService` object a partial mock. (Partial mocks will use the real class behavior except for the parts you mock out).  You do this by setting `CallBase = true` on the mock object;

```
var ApiServiceMock = new Mock<PosPortalApiService>(mockDependancyResolver.Object, options) 
                    {CallBase = true};

ApiServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetEndpointWithAuthorisation(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
              .Returns(someEndpointObjectOrMockYouCreatedForYourTest);

PosPortalApiService ApiService = ApiServiceMock.Object;
var sut = ApiService.GetStoresInfo("2");
```

Comment: That's exactly what i needed.